# If I have a wide range of training data, how do I standardize the data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

My data ranges from 1e-4 to 1e4, does anyone with experience knows how to put them into an input of CNN.(PS: It's a binary classification, and i use softplus as the output activation.but the loss is still 0.69 and accuracy is 0.5~0.6. I have tried adding BathNormalization,and using the kernel_initializer in Dense layer, but both of them doesn't work)

Comment: Picking an appropriate encoding is half the art. Which is to say: it's an art, not a science, and doing it well requires understanding and thinking hard about the problem domain of the data being modeled (what the values are, yes, but also what they represent, how they correlate with each other, and what kinds of precision you need in your output data -- thus, for instance, whether mapping to a non-linear scale is called for). It's much too broad to be a good SO question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sklearn provides a number of scalers that can be used to address your issue. Which one to use depends upon analysis of your data's distribution. Documentation and examples of use is located [here.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html)

Comment: Thank U, It does help me in addressing the issue.